# Bernoulli numbers and $\pi^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, pi, bernoulli-numbers, rate-of-convergence

It is probably well-known that:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{2n}n^2}{b_{2n+2}}=-\pi^2,
$$
where $b_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.

By a numerical experiment I have found that the quotient
$$
\frac{b_{2n}(n+a_1)(n+a_2)}{b_{2n+2}}
$$
with $a_1=1, a_2=\frac12$ converges to $-\pi^2$ extremely fast. Already $n=35$ gives correctly 20 decimal places of $\pi^2$! No other combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$ is even nearly close to this result. For example $a_1=a_2=\frac12$ gives only two correct decimal places for $n=400$.

What is the secret of this extremely good convergence for $a_1=1, a_2=\frac12$?

Comment: For large n the addition of the constants a1 and a2 really doesn't make a difference. I mean n of order 100

Comment: @lux: it doesn’t affect the limit but it can affect the rate of convergence; that is what is being asked about here.

Comment: @lux It could be expected that it does not make difference. The astonishing fact is that the difference is huge. Try it yourself.

Comment: @Clayton, I agree with your comment, although after n gets sufficiently large we don't really care. To the op, just to clarify, there is no doubt it makes no difference whatsoever to the limit (I. E. You will get - pi^2 for n sufficiently large) but perhaps for small n you get some answers that are closer to the limit than without the constants.

Comment: @lux: I never had doubts about the limit. But you can convince yourself by trying that with a different choice of constants you never get such a precision for "$n$ of order 100". Even with $n=1000000$ you will get only 5 correct decimal places.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{B_{2n+2j-2}}{B_{2n+2j}}\cdot (n+j)\left(n+j-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\pi^2$. For higher of values of $j$, it converges quicker.

Comment: @Endgame It is **exactly** the same with my $n$ equal to your $n+j-1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the formula (at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Bernoulli_numbers_and_the_Riemann_zeta_function)

$$B_{2n} = {(-1)^{n+1} 2 (2n)! \over (2\pi)^{2n}} \zeta(2n)$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).
This gives

$${B_{2n} \over B_{2n+2}} = {(-1) (2\pi)^2 \over (2n+1)(2n+2)} {\zeta(2n) \over \zeta(2n+2)} $$

or, multiplying by $(2n+1)(2n+2)/4$,

$$ {B_{2n} (2n+1) (2n+2) \over 4 B_{2n+2}} = -\pi^2 {\zeta(2n) \over \zeta(2n+2)} $$

The left-hand side is the quotient you asked about.  The right-hand side is essentially 1 for large $n$ - more specifically, as $n \to \infty$, we have $\zeta(2n) = 1 + O(1/4^n)$.

So we have

$$ {B_{2n} \over B_{2n+2}} (n+1/2) (n+1) = -\pi^2 (1 + O(1/4^n)). $$

For any other choice of constants $a_1$ and $a_2$, we have

$$ {B_{2n} \over B_{2n+2}} (n+a_1) (n+a_2) = -\pi^2 {(n+a_1)(n+a_2) \over (n+1/2)(n+1)} (1 + O(1/4^n)). $$

The quotient

$$ {(n+a_1)(n+a_2) \over (n+1/2)(n+1)} = {n^2 + (a_1 + a_2)n + a_1 a_2 \over n^2 + (3/2) n + (1/2) }$$

is $1+O(n^{-2})$ if $a_1 + a_2 = 3/2$ but $\{ a_1, a_2 \} \not = \{ 1/2, 1 \}$, and $1 + O(n^{-1})$ otherwise.  And so we get

$${B_{2n} \over B_{2n+2}} (n+a_1) (n+a_2) = -\pi^2 (1 + O(1/4^n)) (1 + O(n^{-k})) = -\pi^2 (1 + O(n^{-k})$$

with $k = 1$ or $k = 2$ depending on the choice of $a_1$ and $a_2$.   In particular only $(a_1, a_2) = (1/2, 1)$ or $(a_1, a_2) = (1, 1/2)$ gives the $O(1/4^n)$ error term.